# ClassNotFoundException: But the class is in the right place

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, classnotfound

I am working on a large project which runs localy on my computer with tomcat and apache httpd server. I did nothing, I just turned normally my computer on like always and started eclipse and than the server, but from now on, I get an exception:

```
 ERROR com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:260 - Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xx.xxxxxon.xxxeditor.xxx.XXFunctions
```

I had to censor some things, sorry. Its basicly a java package in src/main/java. It's there, i can edit it, save it, open it etc. I cleaned the project, tomcat and did a clean run of eclipse.

Some other ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is "xx.xxxxxon.xxxeditor.xxx.XXFunctions" is an external library or one of your classes ? 
If the first one you may not add the library in the classpath.
If second you may delete .class file of the class in your project under the build directory. Try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Its one of my classes. The target folder, which according to the build path configuration is where the classes will be build. And this folder is greyed out. I can open it, but i cannot find the .class files.

Comment: Be sure you open the target folder from the navigator view, which will not hide `.class` files. Are there any .class files definitely?

Comment: @sickzz1 Right click to project go "Build Path" then "Configure Build Path", check the Source path and output path in the "Source" tab. Moreover, place your project to the top from the "Order and Export" tab.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to censor some things, sorry. Its basicly a java package in src/main/java. It's there, i can edit it, save it, open it etc.

---

the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xx.xxxxxon.xxxeditor.xxx.XXFunctions` is that `jvm` cant find the `class file` and your said *java package* `src/main/java` is a `java file`. And there is a `java file` cant represent there is a `.class file` under your `classpath`.

Comment: Ok sorry, my misstake, I know that the file is  a java file not a package.